# How do I insert 9 random rows from one table into another while also setting other columns in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a words table with:
(id, text)

And a game_words table with:
(word_id, game_id, type)

I'd like to take 9 random id's from the words table (they need to be unique) and add them into the game_words table where word_id is the random id from the words table and game_id and type are set manually.

So something like:

```
INSERT INTO game_words (word_id, game_id, type)
VALUES (SELECT id FROM words ORDER BY random() LIMIT 9, 1, 'RED')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO game_words (word_id, game_id, type)
SELECT id, 1, 'red'
FROM words 
ORDER BY random() LIMIT 9;
```